# swift send params to runaction completion callback

Tags: parameters, swift

I need to transfer parameters to runAction:completion callback or access to sprite, which has this action in swift

I have:

```
sprite.runAction(action, completion: { ... })
```

I need something like

```
for i in 0..10 {
   sprite.runAction(action, completion: {
        println(i) // current row, not row at end of cycle (will be 10)
   })
}
```

or:

```
for i in 0..10 {
   var sprite = sprites[i]
   sprite.runAction(action, completion: {
        println(sprite) // current sprite, not sprite at sprites[10]
   })
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: p.s. Now that the answer is deleted, you should be able to simply *delete* the question. I believe you'll find a `delete` link below the question tags.